# Using TPopup in replace of showmessage on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

From Embarcadero [readme file for XE5](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Release_Notes_for_XE5#On_Android.2C_Use_TPopup_Instead_of_ShowMessage):

> **On Android, Use TPopup Instead of ShowMessage**
>
> ShowMessage can become unresponsive when the user changes the focus in an Android app. We recommend using TPopup instead. When the user changes the focus away from a popup, the popup closes as expected, but it can be easily invoked again.

How would I replace this call using `TPopup`?

```
ShowMessage(SL1[lbxProjects.ItemIndex]);
```

Is this `TPopup` still workable with iOS?

Comment: Hmmm, what was the edit? I see no difference.

Comment: Click the `edited X mins ago` to see what changed. In this case, Marcus added the 'firemonkey' tag. What 'dev notes' are you referring to? (When you cite something like that, you should include a link or reference to what you're referencing, so people can see if there's other information there or whether you're possibly misinterpreting something.)

Comment: It's marked right next to the revision number (in this case, #2, in the same colored band that's displaying Marcus' name in the revision history). :-)

Comment: Ah, thanks! He added a tag. Sorry, Im a nuB :)

Comment: I wonder why Embarcadero did not simple update `ShowMessage()` to use `TPopup` internally, instead of requiring people to re-write their existing code.

Comment: I suspect they will. Issues with `ShowMessage` are known and were found close to RTM. I believe the suggestion to use `TPopup` is a workaround while they work out how best to fix `ShowMessage` et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TPopup` is a standard FireMonkey component [documented here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Controls.TPopup).

As far as I can see it's available on all FireMonkey target platforms.

For an example of its use, check the [docwiki tutorial](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_a_Metropolis_UI_Flyout), which is admittedly about building a Win32 Metropolis app, but still runs through use of a `TPopup`. This tutorial is also manifested as one of the supplied samples: [MetropolisUIFlyoutDemo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/FMX.MetropolisUIFlyoutDemo_Sample).

After running through an example of its usage, you should see it's quite trivial to make a `TPopup` look like a message box. You nee to drop  couple of labels etc. on it and have some code take the message and update one of the labels.